# C# Prism Composite Application module loading

Tags: c#, design-patterns, module, prism

Is there a natural way to register modules within a module for the composite application pattern in prism?

Say we have a module A in a prism WPF application which needs to load and register modules A1,A2,...,An.

It seems to me that the approach to register all the "nested" modules A1 to An in the bootstrapper is a "dirty" one, since these modules belong to module A logically.

Should one load A1 to An manually in the Initialize() method of A or is there a more natural approach which fits well in the general module pattern?

Comment: How do you load the modules (at least module A) at the moment?

Comment: @PVitt With the use of the unity container. It came to my mind that passing the container itself maybe a solution, so that a module can load submodules on its behalf.

Comment: Sorry for that unprecise question. What type of module catalog (e.g. DirectoryModuleCatalog) do you use?

Comment: @PVitt I'm not that far, but for now I'll try it with the container injection itself to load the modules A1...An within module A. Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if A1..An are composable or sharable they should be loaded by bootstrapper so other modules could use it. If only module A will use them i think the best idea is not to treat them like prism modules, because they (probably) are used only to implement functionality of module A and aren't modular pieces of software you're building.